# Why JodaTime Library and JDK OffsetDateTime report Pacific/Norfolk time zone offsets as different? Which one is correct?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Norfolk Island times as per Joda Time");
    IntStream.range(1, 13)
            .forEach(month -> System.out.println(DateTime.now((DateTimeZone.forID("Pacific/Norfolk")))
                    .withYear(2023)
                    .withMonthOfYear(month)
                    .withDayOfMonth(10)
                    .withHourOfDay(2)
                    .withMinuteOfHour(10)
                    .withSecondOfMinute(2)
                    .withMillisOfSecond(0)));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Norfolk Island times as per JDK OffsetDateTime");
    IntStream.range(1, 13)
            .forEach(month -> System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Norfolk"))
                    .withYear(2023)
                    .withMonth(month)
                    .withDayOfMonth(10)
                    .withHour(2)
                    .withMinute(10)
                    .withSecond(2)
                    .withNano(0)));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
}
```

Output:

```
Norfolk Island times as per Joda Time
2023-01-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
2023-02-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
2023-03-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
2023-04-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-05-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-06-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-07-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-08-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-09-10T02:10:02.000+11:00
2023-10-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
2023-11-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
2023-12-10T02:10:02.000+12:00
-------------------------------------
Norfolk Island times as per JDK OffsetDateTime
2023-01-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-02-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-03-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-04-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-05-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-06-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-07-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-08-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-09-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-10-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-11-10T02:10:02+11:00
2023-12-10T02:10:02+11:00
-------------------------------------
```

So as per `JodaTime`, they observe DST, but OffsetDateTime says they do not.

Which one is correct? Or I am doing somthing wrong?

**Java: JDK 1.8.0.311**

**JodaTime: 2.10.10**

Comment: FWIW `ZonedDateTime.of(2023, 2, 25, 0, 0,0,0, ZoneId.of("Pacific/Norfolk"))` using JDK yields `2023-02-25T00:00+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]` in agreement with your Joda-Time results. I wouldn’t usually use the `withXxx` methods of neither JDK date-time classes nor the Joda-Time ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation [java.time.OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#:%7E:text=OffsetDateTime%20is%20an%20immutable%20representation,be%20stored%20in%20an%20OffsetDateTime%20.). OffsetDateTime is just an Instance representation with a time-zone offset attached to it. It doesn't adhere to the full time-zone rules like Daylight savings.

[Norflok Island](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/norfolk-island) does have daylight savings from `October 2nd` to `April 3rd`

What you actually need is [java.time.ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).
If you run your code with the ZonedDateTime object you'll get similar results to `JodaTime`:

```
IntStream.range(1, 13)
    .forEach(month -> System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Norfolk"))
            .withYear(2023)
            .withMonth(month)
            .withDayOfMonth(10)
            .withHour(2)
            .withMinute(10)
            .withSecond(2)
            .withNano(0)));
```

> OUTPUT:

```
2023-01-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-02-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-03-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-04-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-05-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-06-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-07-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-08-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-09-10T02:10:02+11:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-10-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-11-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
2023-12-10T02:10:02+12:00[Pacific/Norfolk]
```